# Do you say "I have gone diving before" or "I have been diving before"?

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct and common expression,
"I have gone diving" or "I have been diving"
"Have you ever gone diving?" or "Have you ever been diving?"

As for skating, snowboarding, snorkeling and snowboarding, should I use "go" or "been"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming "diving" here is referring to scuba given the other examples are destination sports. I would tend to say they are interchangeable for those kinds of activities that occur someplace other than where the speaking is occurring. The "been" slightly emphasizes being in the state of doing that activity, while "gone" slightly emphasizes the trip, but most speakers aren't trying to make that fine of a distinction. They just want to know if you've participated in the activity, and either works for that purpose.

In the sitting-by-the-pool example that @jeffrey-kemp gives, it's true that "I have been diving" makes sense and "I have gone diving" does not. That's because there is nowhere to go -- you're already at the pool. However, if you are planning a scuba trip to Belize and you want to determine whether you friend needs to take a scuba class, you can use either "Have you ever gone diving?" or "Have you ever been diving?" -- doesn't matter which.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I want to know about others' experience of the diving, both "Have you ever been diving" and "Have you ever gone diving?" make sense. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. (Also, no "the" before diving if you're talking about diving in general and not a specific occurrence; so you'd say "others' diving experience" not "others' experience of the diving").

Comment: It was very kind of you to correct my mistake in the sentence. Thank you for very much.

Answer (score 1):

The two statements answer slightly different questions.

Typically "gone" in this context implies a trip and a destination, so "I have gone diving" means I went to a place suitable for diving, and dove. Someone calls me and asks where I am, and I might say "I have gone diving".

"I have been diving" might be something I'd say to someone while we are both at that location - so I'm sitting on the edge of the pool, and someone asks me what I've been doing. "I have been diving" would be more appropriate than "I have gone diving".

Or perhaps, if someone calls me and they know I'm at the pool and they ask me what I've been doing, I might say "I have been diving".

"Have you ever been diving?" is not quite right - it would make more sense to ask "Have you ever gone diving?" or maybe "Have you ever dove?"